# Convert data.frame columns to vectors

Tags: r, dataframe

Two different ways to create `data.frame` lead to different result:

```
a <- c(1,2)
b <- c(3,4)
df1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(a, b))
df1
str(df1)
mean(df1$a)
```

This works fine but:

```
a <- list(1,2)
b <- list(3,4)
df2 <- as.data.frame(cbind(a, b))
df2
str(df2)
mean(df2$a)
```

leads to warning:

```
[1] NA
Warning message:
In mean.default(df2$a) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

I encounter this problem when parsing a json file into `data.frame`, I found that I made a mistake assuming that a column of `data.frame` is always `vector`, but it could be `list` instead. When it's a `list`, not only `mean`, many other functions like `summary`and `as.Date` won't work as expected. So now the data type `data.frame` are no longer "safe" to me, passing `data.frame` as input without knowing how it is created means I need to convert its columns to `vector` explicitly, and there might be more complicated issue where `list` and `vector` coexist:

```
df3 <- df2
df3$a <- as.numeric(df3$a)
str(df3)
```

So I tried to convert all columns to `vector`:

```
data.frame(lapply(df3, function(x) {if (is.list(x)) do.call(c, x) else x}))
```

But I found it too verbose, are there any better solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
data.frame(lapply(df3, unlist))
```

Produces:

```
'data.frame': 2 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ a: num  1 2
 $ b: num  3 4
```